# Sub stringing a column by a number of characters after a certain value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a field that looks like this:  `Non Compliance Risk Situation 1 - domain D-G101 Regulatory licenses and relations with regulators`.  I want to create a new column that starts after "domain" and contains only the value `D-G101`.  All the rows have the same format.

Any help will be appreciated

```
osi['col'] = osi.Name.str.split('domain').str.slice(start=7)     
# I expected to get 'D-G101'. Instead I get [] for col
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using a simple regex pattern to extract the relevant information would be the better choice instead of split.

```
osi['col'] = osi['Name'].str.extract(r'domain (\S+)')
```

Or if you want more restrictive with a regex pattern

```
osi['col'] = osi['Name'].str.extract(r'domain ([A-Z0-9-]+)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.extract` to capture the needed substring:

```
osi['col'] = osi['Name'].str.extract(r'(?<=domain )(\w-\w{4})')[0]
```

Comment: Great. Thanks Roman. Works like a peach!